# Possible to build secure https links with g:form and g:link in grails 2.x?

Tags: grails, https, spring-security

This is similar to my as of yet unanswered question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825422/can-grails-redirect-command-be-told-to-respect-protocol-of-the-current-request but in this case I simply want to ensure certain links and form actions I specify to controllers are explicitly https.  I know I could build these links manually, but that defeats the purpose of the tags automatically adding the correct hostname, application path, etc.

In a perfect world the links would be relative if I was on an https page, and absolute if not, but I'll take absolute links always if that isn't possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There's an [open jira](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-3625) for this request.

I think you can create your own tag lib to do this work. Just call `g.createLink` and replace http for https.

```
class MyTagLib {
  def secureLink = { attrs, body ->
    def link = g.createLink(attrs)
    out << link.replace('http','https')
  }
}
```

Comment: Great - I extended your approach with a custom attribute to allow the creation of protocol relative links.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to do this would be to configure your `grails.serverURL` in `Config.groovy` to use the https protocol. Then use `absolute="true"` in your [gsp form tags](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/form.html) and link tags.

Comment: But this would change ALL links.  I want to set only specific links (as only certain pages are https protected under Spring Security Plugin's channel security

Answer (score 0):

extending Sergios solution, but forcing absolute="true":

```
class MyTagLib {
  def secureLink = { attrs, body ->
    // forcing creation of an absolute url
    attrs.absolute = 'true'

    def link = g.createLink(attrs)
    out << link.replaceFirst(/^http:/, 'https:')
  }
}
```

or for your "perfect world" scenario, you could try this:

```
class MyTagLib {
  def secureLink = { attrs, body ->
    if (!request.isSecure()) {
      attrs.absolute = 'true'
      def link = g.createLink(attrs)
      out << link.replaceFirst(/^http:/, 'https:')
    } else {
      out << g.createLink(attrs)
    }
  }
}
```